# Boolean logic simplification wy'+wx'y+wxyz+wxz' am I doing this right?

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, algebra

I'm studying for my digital logic test tomorrow, and I'm doing some practice problems. I'm having problems with this one specifically. I think I solved it, but I'm not confident in my answer. Can anyone verify the logic and explain it? I have looked elsewhere but can't find the answer previously recorded anywhere.

```
wy'+wx'y+wxyz+wxz'
```

**1.** I factored `wy` out of `wx'y` and `wxyz` to get `wy(x'+xz)` which equates to `wy(x'+z)`. Using the rule `A+A'B = A+B`

This changes the equation to `wy'+wyx'+wyz+wxz'`

**2.** I factored `w` out of `wy'` and `wyx'` to get `w(y'+yx')` which equates to `w(y'+x')`. Using the rule `A+ A'B = A+B`.

This changes the equation to `wy'+wx'+wyz+wxz'`

**3.** I factored `w` out of `wy'` and `wyz` to get `w(y'+yz)` which equates to `w(y'+z')`. Using the same rule again.

This changes the equation to `wy'+wz'+wyx'+wxz'`

**4.** I factored `w` out of wz' and wxz' to get `w(z'+z'x)` which equates to `w(z')` using the rule `A+AB=A`.

This changes the equation to `wz'+wy'+wyx'`

**5.** I factored w out of `wy'` and `wyx'` to get `w(y'+yx')` which equates to `w(y'+x')` using the rule `A+A'B = A+B`.

This changes the equation to `wy'+wx'+wz'` - This is where I am stuck, I feel like there are more steps to do, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake in Step 3

you start with

```
wy'+wx'+wyz+wxz' (equivalent to wy'+wyz+wx'+wxz')
```

you then correctly factor `w` out of `wy'` and `wyz` to get `w(y'+yz)`

but then you suggest `w(y'+yz)` is equal to `w(y'+z')` (which is incorrect)

```
w(y'+yz) is equal to w(y'+z)
```

which leaves you with `wy'+wz+wyx'+wxz'` (instead of `wy'+wz'+wyx'+wxz'`)

after which the remaining logic after Step 3 will need to be adjusted

Comment: Ahh thank you so much, I was pulling my hair out. I will update the answer when I calculate it.

Comment: Okay after calculating the error out my final answer is just W. Is that correct?

Comment: That's what I got too. :)